# Is there a pre-made clang-tidy clion configuration for C++03?

Tags: clion, c++03, clang-tidy

CLion has a nice [integration of Clang-Tidy](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2017/04/clion-2017-2-eap-clang-tidy/), but the default configuration is targeted to modern C++. The compiler I'm stuck with however is C++03 only and all the advices of Clang-Tidy on modernizing my code just continue to rub in the fact that my compiler is very old.

I have identified already a couple of [checks](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/list.html) that must be deactivated for C++03, but this list is surely far from complete:

- `boost-use-to-string`
- all `modernize-use-*` checks

Does anybody have compiled a list of checks to deactivate for C++03?

Comment: Also see [Language level for clang-tidy "modernize-*" checks](https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2017-August/054918.html) on the LLVM dev mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no standard way to disable all irrelevant Clang-Tidy checks for old compilers in CLion.
Clang-Tidy was initially designed to modernize whole code base to new C++ standards and many checks ignore fact with old standards.

But you can easily setup and disable all irrelevant checks for your project right from context-menu:
[disable Clang-Tidy from context-menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYocl.png)

By this, you can disable particular check (e.g. `modernize-use-nullptr`), whole group (e.g. all `modernize-*` inspections) or you can suppress Clang-Tidy for current line by inserting `//NOLINT` comment at the end of line.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Also see [Language level for clang-tidy "modernize-*" checks](https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2017-August/054918.html) on the LLVM dev mailing list.